# Cordova run(device) is not responding

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, debugging, usb

I'm trying to build a Cordova android app in Visual studio. When I `run` in `device` It's stuck at this:

```
Installing apk C:/Users/Saicom/source/repos/Tesseract/Tesseract/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk on target GBAXGV902424VGJ...
2>Running command: C:\Users\Saicom\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s GBAXGV902424VGJ install -r C:/Users/Saicom/source/repos/Tesseract/Tesseract/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

I can see adb.exe is being executed in task manager windows but nothing happening. `USB debugging` mode is already active in my android phone and connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed when I rebooted target device.

Comment: Really thank you for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other members who get the same issue.